# Каким образом это можно сделать?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть сайт: [С очень прикольным эффектом](https://badassfilms.tv/real/yann-gorriz/)
Обшарил его вдоль и поперек, но не смог понять как они получили эффект для текста при прокрутке страницы. Интересует больше всего заливка текста, но если кто могет рассказать как сделать и наклоны при скролле, то буду весьма и весьма признателен.

Comment: Вижу только картинку и текст в углу. На прокрутку сайт не реагирует абсолютно никак https://i.stack.imgur.com/r486X.png

Comment: Текст появляется после того как загрузиться фоновое видео.

Answer (score 1):

Этот эффект подробно разобрал Юра Артюх у себя на youtube канале в одном из выпусков. Возможно тебе будет интересно посмотреть, вот [ссылка на видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQMryV9X1R4). Удачи!